# How do i add the objects that the raycast is hitting in unity and add them to a list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have this problem that i just can't figure out how to solve.
I am trying to make a game in Unity, and i have stumbled across a problem that goes like this.

I want to put an object in the scene in a list, when i hit it with a raycast.

With what i have tried so far. Either it puts everything that is tagged the same thing on the list when i press mousebutton on one of the objects, or it only puts in the same thing (Cube in this example).

My code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTagged : MonoBehaviour
{
public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;

public Camera fpsCam;

public List<GameObject> playersTagged;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();

        if (target != null)
        {
            target.takeDamage(damage);
            if(hit.collider.tag == "Taggable")
            playersTagged.Add(GameObject.FindWithTag("Taggable"));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
playersTagged.Add(hit.collider.gameObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using GameObject.FindWithTag() which returns the first object it'll find [source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)

Use gameobject property playersTagged.Add(target.gameobject). Since all components store the reference to the gameobject they are attached to.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `GameObject.FindWithTag("Taggable")` which means you are getting any GameObject that has that tag and adding it to the list. But instead, you want to add the hit object, so you need to add `hit.collider.gameObject`.

Comment: `you are getting all GameObjects` .. nope only always the first one ;) you can not `Add` multiple elements to a list without using `AddRange` ;)

Comment: you're right @derHugo. Edited!